# Efficient way to if else statement with hundreds of blocks

Tags: javascript

I've got a list of hundreds of numbers that the user can click on, each number corresponds with a scene variable that ends with the same number the user clicks on, ie if user picked "43", renderer.render(scene43,camera) is performed.

```
//jumpSwitcher is defined the numerical value that the user has clicked on 
jumpSwitcher = +value;

if (jumpSwitcher == 1) {
     renderer.render(scene1, camera);
} else if (jumpSwitcher == 2) {
     renderer.render(scene2, camera);
}
```

This could go on hundreds of times though. How do I write the above code so that I may save myself a lot of work. And how do I efficiently define an array worth of hundreds of these scene variables?

Comment: `switch(case)` > `if/else` http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: use a `switch`? Have an array of `scenes` and just do `renderer.render(scenes[jumpSwitcher], camera)`? Consider a state machine?

Comment: An array containing the scenes and then accessing each using `jumpSwitcher[scene]` sounds like the easiest way to go

Comment: make combinations in a dictionary or lookup table

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Just simply write this:

```
"use strict";
renderer.render(eval('scene' + jumpSwitcher), camera);
```

And you don't need `if` or `switch`.

**UPDATE:** Strict mode added for safer `eval()`, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: With `eval()` comes great responsibility

Comment: @Giovane can you please elaborate more what you trying to point out

Comment: @anshu the `eval` function is something really really delicate that you need be aware when using it. It you execute anything passed as argument to it, really anything. I know that it way be the only answer for some specific super problems, but for simple use I see the usage of it as Laziness.
Unless you treat the data passed as argument to it, it is pure evil!
Take a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @István I saw, interesting. I didn't know about eval and strict mode, I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Giovane: Don't use eval. There are better ways. (See the other answers).

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, I never see eval as an option hahaha

Comment: Using strict mode does not make `eval` any safer, that's very misleading. It prevents existing code from using the results of the `eval`, but does nothing to sanitize input.

Comment: Strict mode doesn't solve anything with regards to eval. The only thing that'd actually help is "variable safe eval" as specified by Miller in http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37199.html or as in https://github.com/FUDCo/proposal-frozen-realms

Comment: when the person have 10,000 if-else conditions ? now compare it with eval() . I am not sure eval() will win or loose in this condition. Just curious to know who will win "10,000 if-else" or "eval"

Comment: @anshu: There are other options that are faster than both `eval` and 10k `if-else` statements.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using "literal object"

```
var conditions = {
    "1": ..., // treat condition to 1
    "2": ... // treat condition to 2
    "default": ... // default treatment
}

var treatment = conditions[scene] || conditions.default;
```

Comment: I don't see how map would resolve that question. Could you give an example?

Comment: *A* [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is one of the new ES6 collections, meant to replace objects for key-value lookups. They're very similar, map is just a more formal way of expressing this.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. I did't know it. I thought you were talking about the array.map

Answer (score 5):

Use an array.

```
var scenes = [ null, scene1, scene2, scene3 ];
renderer.render(scenes[jumpSwitcher], camera);
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use eval(), but [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/6877504).

You can populate a scenes array using this:

```
scenes = Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(function () {return new Scene();});
```

Alternatively, with ES6,

```
scenes = Array.from(Array(100), () => new Scene())
```

Then just use:

```
renderer.render(scenes[jumpSwitcher-1], camera);
```

Comment: You'd do `Array.apply(null, Array(100))` for a new empty array? It actually sounds like clean code? You can do `Array.from({length: 100}, () => new Scene)` instead of that line. Even `''.repeat(100).split("").map(x => new Scene)` is cleaner or heaven forbid a for loop/generator.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I agree it is really ugly. I just used it because it is compatbile with older browsers. I guess that would be a better solution, I'd prefer `Array.from(Array(100))` from a cleanness point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either an array, if you have contiguous numbers

```
scenes = [scene0, scene1, ..., sceneN ]
// access
renderer.render(scenes[scene], camera);
```

or an object for numbers with gaps

```
scenes = { 10: scene10, 15: scene15 }
// access
renderer.render(scenes[scene], camera);
```

or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
scenes = new Map([[4, scene4], [20, scene20]]);
// access
renderer.render(scenes.get(scene), camera);
```

The other possibillity is to use the programming style *return early*, which means, to make a condition and end the function if the condition is met.

```
function callScene(scene) {
    if (scene === 1) {
        renderer.render(scene1, camera);
        return;
    }
    if (scene === 2) {
        renderer.render(scene2, camera);
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think this could be a good answer if you demoed using the array/object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the switch statement, example

```
switch(jumpSwitcher)
{
    case 1: {renderer.render(scene1, camera); break;}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the scenes appear to be global variables, you can also use this:

```
renderer.render(window['scene' + jumpSwitcher], camera);
```

No `eval`, single line, variable `scene` number... It doesn't get any more simple than this.

If the scenes aren't on `window`, replace it with the proper scope object. (`this`, for example).

Comment: Probably better to use an array.

Comment: No doubt, @BenjaminGruenbaum. But still better than `eval`.